# Isn't possible to send an UDP Broadcast in some computers

Tags: sockets, udp, broadcast

Why is it not possible to send a UDP Broadcast in some computers?

I've tested with [Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/download), and it works in some computers in my company, and in others it is not possible to send.

There is another software from VIRDI company, called [TerminalFinder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B06Dxl8hzdKDcDNsdHM0dzF5enM), which sends UDP broadcasts at port 9870, but the same problem occurs.

I want to know if it is necessary to configure something in the network properties of the computers (Win 7 or Win 10) to make this work.

Comment: Is the UDP broadcast being sent to the generic `255.255.255.255` broadcast address, or a subnet-specific broadcast address, like `192.168.0.255`? Are the affected computers behind a firewall? Or on another subnet?  Some firewalls may block UDP broadcasts to the generic address but allow broadcasts to a specific subnet. Some routers may block UDP broadcasts from span across subnet boundaries. Or, they might be blocking UDP broadcasts altogether.  Check your network configurations.

Comment: The Broadcast is being sent to 255.255.255.255.
So, you think it can be the firewall, and not the configuration of the PC. I will do more tests.

Comment: I am only speculating, since you have not provided any details about your PC or network setup.  It is *possible* that a firewall *might* be blocking it. That is one of many possibilities. In any case, unless you are writing your own broadcasting code, this line of questioning is off-topic for StackOverflow. Questions about general software should be directed to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). Questions about network administration should be directed to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).